# Output arrays in object in Javascript for spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

This is my code.

```
function order() {

  //declare things
var order = [3, 2, 1, 0]
var testOne = [2, 3, 7, 4]
var testTwo = ["c", "b", "a", "d"]


//sort by order
  var collatedArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++)
    {
        index = order[i];
        var collated =
        {
           test1 : testOne[index],
           test2 : testTwo[index]
        }
        collatedArray.push(collated);
    }


  //Create output
  var output = [];
  for (i=0; i<collatedArray.length; i++)
  {
    output[i] = collatedArray[i].test1
  }

return output
}
```

The output currently is only collatedArray[i].test1, which gives:

```
4, 7, 3, 2
```

If I change output[i] = collatedArray[i].test1 to test2, I get:

```
d, a, b, c
```

I just want to output the whole collatedArray (test1 and test2) so that I get:

```
4, 7, 3, 2
d, a, b, c
```

without the need for output variable, or converting back to arrays. The info is all there I just can't figure out how to get it out. Very new to coding, just not understanding what to do here :(
Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused about how you want your data to look when you return it.  Are you looking for something like `[4, 7, 3, 2, d, a, b, c]`?

Comment: How are you using this function? Output where? Seems like a waste creating `collatedArray` and not returning it to whereever you need this data

Comment: @senschen something like i've posted above, a new row for test1 and test2 and potentially test3 etc when I add it. It's to make a table in a spreadsheet

Comment: @charlietfl I'm transposing the data in a spreadsheet, with =transpose(order()). Yes it is a waste, that's what I'm trying to do. I want to return collatedArray and not use output, but it just gives me blank data I can't figure out how to output an array of objects.

Comment: Then couldn't you just return `collatedArray` as-is, and use `[someobj].test1` to get the first row, and `[someobj].test2` to get the second?  Or do you want them in a string, separated by a newline character?

Comment: @senschen Yes I would like to return collatedArray. How do I do that? return collatedArray gives me no data in my spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Adjust `output` to an array containing two arrays; within last `for` loop populate each array within `output` with values at `collatedArray[0][i].test1` and `collatedArray[1][i].test2`

```
  // Create output
  var output = [[], []]; 
  for (i=0; i<collatedArray.length; i++)
  {
    output[0][i] = collatedArray[i].test1;
    output[1][i] = collatedArray[i].test2;
  }
```

---

```js
function order() {

  //declare things
  var order = [3, 2, 1, 0]
  var testOne = [2, 3, 7, 4]
  var testTwo = ["c", "b", "a", "d"]


  //sort by order
  var collatedArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
    index = order[i];
    var collated = {
      test1: testOne[index],
      test2: testTwo[index]
    }
    collatedArray.push(collated);
  }


  //Create output
  var output = [
    [],
    []
  ];
  for (i = 0; i < collatedArray.length; i++) {
    output[0][i] = collatedArray[i].test1;
    output[1][i] = collatedArray[i].test2;
  }

  return output
}

console.log(order())
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work yes. But is there not a way to just output the objects in collatedArray without creating the new output array to move them into that? Can't figure out how

Comment: _"But is there not a way to just output the objects in collatedArray without creating the new output array to move them into that?"_  Yes, you could return `collatedArray` from `order` . What is expected output ? a) Two arrays containing values of objects; b) one array containing values from both objects; c)  single array containing four objects ? See original Question at _"I just want to output the whole collatedArray (test1 and test2) so that I get:

4, 7, 3, 2
d, a, b, c"_

Comment: Expected output is: "4, 7, 3, 2" new row "d, a, b, c". If I just comment out the whole bottom part of my code and change to return collatedArray, in my spreadsheet i get zero data when using =order(). Whereas your solution does give me the expected output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"Expected output is: 4, 7, 3, 2 newline d, a, b, c."_ Expected output is string, not array ?

Comment: It's both arrays. Or all arrays located within collatedArray.

Comment: @Ser3nity _"It's both arrays. Or all arrays located within collatedArray."_  That is current ouput at `js` at stacksnippets ? _"Whereas your solution does give me the expected output."_  Not certain what issue, expected result is ?  If expected output is string with newline character separating arrays of `output`, try  `var ordered = order(), res = "";
ordered.forEach(function(val, index) {
  res += val.toString() + (index === 0 ? "\n" : "")
});console.log(res)` jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o3n4atk7/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you can do this, including storing each testNumber (`testOne`, `testTwo`, etc) in an object consisting of properties. Learn how **objects** work and you should, having observed your code here, easily be able to figure out how to loop through each property (which in your case will be arrays) of said `Object` to print out what you're looking for. If you can't figure it out, there are plenty of Stack Overflow Q&A's that cover this phenomenally well.

But for now, here is a simple alternative: an array of arrays.

https://jsfiddle.net/6r3hv3aq/7/

```
var testOne = [2,3,7,4];
var testTwo = ["c","b","a","d"];

var test = [testOne,testTwo];

for (var i = 0; i <= test.length-1; i++) {
    console.log(test[i]);
}
```

Which will output exactly what you asked for:

```
[2, 3, 7, 4]
["c", "b", "a", "d"]
```

*Note: When you click the jsfiddle link provided, you may have to refresh the page to see the appropriate results loaded into the console. Alternatively, leave the console open when you migrate to the link.*

Answer (score 0):

Since you're wanting this for a spreadsheet I am assuming you want a CSV output string that you can import into a spreadsheet program.

```
function row(source, sequence) {
  var temp = new Array(sequence.length);    
  for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++)
    temp[i] = source[sequence[i]];
  return temp.join(",")
}

function order() {

  //declare things
  var sequence = [3, 2, 1, 0];
  var testOne = [2, 3, 7, 4];
  var testTwo = ["c", "b", "a", "d"];

  var rows = [];
  rows.push(row(testOne, sequence));
  rows.push(row(testTwo, sequence));
  return rows.join("\r\n");
}
```

[Here's a plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ople377egPkqYaeklFYo?p=preview)